# Deserializing "Unwrapped" Json Arrays to POJO

Tags: jackson, deserialization

Half of my problem is not knowing the exact terms to search for an answer. I *believe* I'm dealing with what's called a "flat" or "unwrapped" json array with the underlying "members" node in that this would work if there was a "member:" element for each of the "members" underlying property nodes, but there isn't.

I receive json (I can't control format) that looks like this:

```
{

  "id" : "1",

  "context" :

  {

    "id" : "123,

    "title" : "My Title"

  },

  "members": [

    {

      "prop1" : { },

      "prop2" : "123",

      "propArray1" : [ "Value1", "Value2" ],

      "prop3" : "xyz",

      "prop4" : "123"

    },

    {

      "prop1" : { },

      "prop2" : "456",

      "propArray1" : [ "Value1", "Value2" ],

      "prop3" : "abc",

      "prop4" : "456"

    }

  ] }
```

My POJO (minus the simple gets/sets):

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class MyPojo {

    @JsonProperty
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private Context context;
    @JsonProperty("members")
    private List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonAutoDetect
    public class Context {
        public Context() {}

        @JsonProperty
        private String id;
        @JsonProperty
        private String title;
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect
    public class Member {

        public Member() {}

        @JsonProperty
        private String prop1;
        @JsonProperty
        private String prop2;
        @JsonProperty
        private List<String> propArray1 = new ArrayList<>();
        @JsonProperty
        private String prop3;
        @JsonProperty
        private String prop4;
        @JsonProperty
        private String prop5;

    }

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(List<Member> members) {
        this.members = members;
    }
}
```

I've tried GSON:

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonEntity, MyPojo.class);

returns:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

I've tried Jackson:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonEntity, MyPojo.class);

throws:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class MyPojo$Member]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5c6e5b53; line: 10, column: 3] (through reference chain: MyPojo["members"])
```

I don't think "add/enable" type information is a relevant warning and I do have the default constructor.

I've searched dozens of json deserialization posts and this one seems similar to this but I have to get the entire Json object not just a piece of it...and I tried it just to extract members array and it didn't work.

[Cannot deserialize JSON to POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216894/cannot-deserialize-json-to-pojo)

Answer (score 0):

there are some issues here:

the JSON testdata is not valid (missing closing " at second id). corrected version:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "context" :
{
  "id" : "123",
  "title" : "My Title"
},
"members": [
{
  "prop1" : { },
  "prop2" : "123",
  "propArray1" : [ "Value1", "Value2" ],
  "prop3" : "xyz",
  "prop4" : "123"
},
{
  "prop1" : { },
  "prop2" : "456",
  "propArray1" : [ "Value1", "Value2" ],
  "prop3" : "abc",
  "prop4" : "456"
}
] }
```

second issue: nested classes by default have a reference to the enclosing class. one consequence of this is that they cannot be created without an instance of the enclosing class. Jackson i get this exception:

```
 Cannot construct instance of `foo.MyPojo$Member` (although at least one Creator exists)
```

fix this by converting the nested classes to static inner classes:

```
 public static class Context {
    ...
 }
```

third issue: the mapping does not match the JSON.

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
...
(through reference chain: foo.MyPojo["members"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->foo.MyPojo$Member["prop1"])
```

fix this by changing the mapping. e.g:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public static class Member {

    public Member() {}

    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, String> prop1;
    ...
}
```

Using this 3 changes its possible to deserialize the JSON using Jackson.